# Check inequality for probabilities

Tags: probability, inequality

Suppose we have a vector $v = (v_1, \dots, v_n)$. We know that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n v_i = 0, \sum\limits_{i=1}^n |v_i| \le 2$.

Also we have stochastic matrix $P$ such that $\min\limits_{i,j}p_{ij} \ge \varepsilon > 0$. So, we define a new vector $y = Pv$.

I need to prove that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |y_i| \le \big(1-n\varepsilon\big)\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |v_i|$. Could you give me some hints of how to prove this?

Comment: Hint :Write $y_j=\sum(p_{j,k}-\varepsilon)v_k+\varepsilon\sum v_k$.

Comment: @Kelenner, think about this several minutes, no result. Could you give me next step to the proof?

Comment: You have $\sum v_k=0$. Hence $y_j=\sum(p_{j,k}-\varepsilon)v_k$.

Comment: @Kelenner, yes, this step was done. Then I have tried to prove something like that $|y_j| \le (1-n\varepsilon)|v_j|, \forall j$, but this seems to be false. Another way is to evaluate the sum as $\sum(p_{j,k}-\varepsilon)v_k \le \frac{1-n\varepsilon}{n}\sum|v_k|$ but it's not that simple

Comment: You have $|y_j|\leq \sum _k |p_{j,k}-\varepsilon||v_k|= \sum _k (p_{j,k}-\varepsilon)|v_k|$ by the fact that $p_{i,j}\geq \varepsilon$. Hence $\sum_j|y_j|\leq \sum_j\sum_k ( p_{j,k}-\varepsilon)|v_k|=\sum_k |v_k|(\sum_j(p_{j,k}-\varepsilon))$. Now compute $\sum_j(p_{j,k}-\varepsilon)$.

Comment: @Kelenner, oh, I multiplied $Pv$ in the wrong way. I forgot that we have to transpose $P$ and so the columns sum to 1, not rows. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are welcome.